# NetBeans Xdebug max simultaneous connections

Tags: php, netbeans, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using NetBeans to debug php with xdebug, everything works perfect but when there are several connections in the same script I'm debugging.

I've seen that PhpStorm provides a configuration check: simultaneous connections https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/04/simultaneous-debugging-sessions-in-phpstorm/

I would like to know if NetBeans can manage simultaneous connections and how to activate it?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code now, it is much better and debugging works great.

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans can debug php with simultaneous connections, though this is dependent upon both the constraints of the php interpreter and what you're doing with those connections. Check your server's php.ini for max_connections and if you're doing something like connecting to a database, make sure you're closing out the connections when finished with them. @Black's answer of VSCode is probably a better option than NetBeans. I use PHPStorm, but used NetBeans years ago.

Comment: Yes, just use VSCode until netbeans fully supports xdebug. It is free, has a bigger community and it is easier to use.